# Weighted projective lines and elliptic curves

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, modular-curves

The modular curves of low level can sometimes be describes as weighted projective lines. For example, over $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ the compactified stack of elliptic curves with full level 2 structure is isomorphic to the projective line of degree $(2, 2)$. Over $\mathbb{Z}[1/3]$ the compactified stack fo elliptic curves with $\Gamma_1(3)$ level structure is isomorphism to the projective line of degree $(1, 3)$ (as mentioned by L Meier in Examples 2.1 https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.03461).

Is there an explicit description of the compactified stack of elliptic curves with full level 3 structure written down somewhere?

Comment: The compactified stack of elliptic curves with full level 3 structure is actually just the ordinary $\mathbb P^1$, at least over $\mathbb Z[1/3]$.

Comment: @WillSawin are you sure? I think over $\mathbb{Z}[1/3]$ it is something connected, and it has 2 connected components after tensoring with $\mathbb{Z}[1/3][\zeta]$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive cubic root of $1$ (so it is not the projective line, which remains connected after tensoring with any integral domain).

Comment: @user145468 You're completely right, but anyways it's not some weighted projective line, but rather the ordinary projective line over $\mathbb Z[1/3][\zeta]$, viewed as a scheme over $\mathbb Z[1/3]$.